# How change the color of selected value of input text

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of selected "XYZ" to other color. Currently if i select the "XYZ" then selected color id blue but i want to give other color.Could anybody please tell me how to do that.

```css
input[type=text] {
  border: none;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled value="xyz">
```

Comment: How are you trying to *select the "XYZ"*?

Comment: by double clicking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - set the background color of ::selection in an INPUT or TEXTAREA in webkit / chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366168/css-set-the-background-color-of-selection-in-an-input-or-textarea-in-webkit)

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Comment: You cannot select text in disabled input elements.

Comment: Use ::selection selector but please remember that it is not allowed to select a text in a disabled input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for:

```
<input type="color" value="#some_hex" id="color-input">
```

You can then grab the value from that input using JavaScript and assing to the style property of other element.